# How to Post imageData(video) from Jsp to Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, video, canvas

The Code I use to get the image data and post it is like this, and the imageData is an Uint8ClampedArray and it is a video stream. but I got a error msg every time when I try to submit it. the msg is "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
$.ajax({
    url: '/blog/saveblog',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{videoData: videoData},
    success: function (result) {
        loadMine();
    }
});
```

the server is built in Spring mvc, I wrote a controller to handle this post request, but it never get in.

Can anyone help me on this problem? thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but if it can help someone...

here is one way to POST canvas data to your server

```
    function(canvas) {
        $.post('/blog/saveblog',
             {
                image: canvas.toDataURL()
              },
              function(data) {...});
      }
```

And a way to manage it on the server side using spring MVC

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveblog")
    @ResponseBody
    public void saveBlog(@RequestParam(value="image", required=false) String imageBase64) throws IOException
        long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        byte[] bytes = imageBase64.replaceAll("data:image/.+;base64,", "").getBytes();

        File image= new File("./folder", "image.jpeg");

        if(!image.exists()){
            Files.createParentDirs(image);
        }
        Files.write(DECODER.decode(bytes), image);
    }
```

This works fine for images, I think it should also work for video (need to change line *imageBase64.replaceAll("data:image/.+;base64,", "")*)